# Get variable value from protected method in another class

Tags: java, android, protected

Brand new to Android and Java...

I have a `protected` method in `Class2` as follows:

```
protected void onListClick(List 2, View view, int position, long id)
{

.....

int Count = cursor.GetInt(countIndex);

........
}
```

I need access the value from `Count` from `Class2`.

in the `Class1`(where trying to access value from Class2) I have `int getValue = Class2.Count;`

Why is this not working?

Comment: Look into what a **local** variable is.

Comment: `Count`'s scope is only within the method it is declared. If you need to access it from another class, declare it outside the method as a class member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Count` is a local variable, so it cannot be accessed by other classes. You can make a static class member of `Class2` instead.

```
class Class2 {
    static int Count;
    ...
    protected void onListClick(List 2/*invalid name*/, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        ...
        Count = cursor.GetInt(countIndex);
        ...
    }
}
```

A suggestion for the future: name all variables and methods using `camelCase`, and never with numbers or special characters. Some incorrect examples from your code: int `Count`, List `2`, `GetInt()`.

Comment: the parameter List 2 is not allowed. The parameter can be changed instead to two or anything but not special case or number or keywords.

Comment: Thanks!  However was advised to declare method using Capital first to distinguish between variable; i.e. variable = myVariable, method = MyMethod.  Is this not correct then?

Comment: Conventionally, variable and method names are camelCase, while class names are MixedCase.